# ON INSERT: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I have no code behind and the above error keep prompting on INSERT.  The DBML is refresh!

Exception Details: System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have a look at this forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1199308.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

Sounds to me like **Identity Specification** is not enabled on the table's index column. Enable it and update the DBML.

Of course, if your primary key is something that doesn't support Identity Specification, you will need to generate your own primary keys. Entity Framework doesn't use default values you may have set for a column, so if you use a *uniqueidentifier* column and have set the default value to *NEWID()*, that might be your problem. In that case, use

```
myObject.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

from your code.

Comment: Perfect Solution. Very important update DBML which mostly forget :-)

Comment: Update the .dbml file:  Yup, this solved it for me aswell... damn !!