# System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use

Tags: linq, insert, duplicates, unit-of-work

mine is windows application. I am trying to insert a record through a LINQ DataContext. It has Unique identifier in the table. Even i am executing a trigger after insertion. So i am making a select query in the end of the trigger to get the auto generator number and to avoid auto-sync error. As it's a windows application i can keep the Context for longtime. When i create a new object ( for example order) and do the same previous operation, upon SubmitChanges operation, it shows cannot have duplicate key. Can't i use this same Context to Insert the second record? Or do i need to create a new Context to insert a new Record?(Does this Unit of work Concept comes here?). Creating new Context is bad idea as i need to load all data again..

Any thought?

Let me put some code sample to voice my situation.

```
CallCenterLogObjCotext = (CallCenterLogObjCotext == null ? (new CallcenterLogContext) : (CallCenterLogObjCotext));

CallDetail newCallDetailsOpenTicket = new CallDetail();

newCallDetailsOpenTicket.CallPurpose = (from callpuposelist in CallCenterLogObjCotext.CallPurposes where callpuposelist.CallPurposeID == ((CallPurpose)(cbcallpurpose.SelectedItem)).CallPurposeID select callpuposelist).FirstOrDefault();
```

Lots of settings like this ...

```
CallCenterLogObjCotext.CallDetails.InsertOnSubmit(newCallDetailsOpenTicket); CallCenterLogObjCotext.SubmitChanges();
```

As i mentioned above, this is a click on Open Ticket button on windows form. I change the values of fname, lname and all in the textboxes available on that form and clicked the same button. So it will call the same method again. I get the below specified error. System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question, it deals with your exception and proposes a solution:

[ON INSERT: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106355/on-insert-cannot-add-an-entity-with-a-key-that-is-already-in-use)